# installing module resources

Tags: magento-1.9, install-script

i am installing tabels for my module can i declare two classes? if not how to i combine both?

```
<global>
    <resources>
        <name_module_setup>
            <setup>
                <module>Name_module</module>
                <class>Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup</class>
                <class>Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Setup</class>
            </setup>
        </name_module_setup>
    </resources>
</global>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your not using combine both classes in one step

Catalog Setup

`Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Setup` Extended `Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup` Extended `Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup`

[More details-1](http://doc4dev.net/doc/Magento/1/class-Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Setup.html)

[More Details-2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/1497/avoid-conflicts-in-setup-scripts-with-multiple-developers)